# Animation callback in CreateJS/EaselJS Framework

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

Is there anyway how can we have animation callback in EaselJs framework? Basically I want to get notified for every animation sequence ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For a sprite sheet animation you can use onAnimationEnd like this:**

```
// create a BitmapAnimation instance to display and play back the sprite sheet:

var bmpAnim = new BitmapAnimation(spriteSheet);

// start playing the first sequence:

bmpAnim.gotoAndPlay("walkRt");

// the callback is called each time a sequence completes:

bmpAnim.onAnimationEnd = angleChange;

Online api doc here:
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/BitmapAnimation.html
```

**If you are using tweens from TweenJS you can use the call function on a tween instance:**

Example:

```
Tween.get(bar, {override:true}).to({x:695}, 1500, easeType).call(tweenComplete);
```

Online api doc here:
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/modules/TweenJS.html

Comment: In EaselJS 0.7.1, the event is called "animationEnd", and the "BitmapAnimation" class has been deprecated in favor of "Sprite". Docs: http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Sprite.html

Comment: @user1417233: Online API doc link is broken.

Comment: http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html#method_stop  updated API link.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend Greensock for tweening instead of tweenjs as it supports better and have more features.

http://www.greensock.com/v12/